# mySql count all latest versions

Tags: mysql, sql, database, cakephp-2.0

In had a question up yesterday unfortunately I didn't explain myself well enough - one of them end of the day things.

Anyway I have a table called documents...

```
+----+--------------------------------------+-----------+---------+---------+
| id | document_guid                        | title     | version | payload |
+----+--------------------------------------+-----------+---------+---------+
| 1  | 0D2753BE-583B-42CE-B0DA-1FD0171D95C0 | animation | 1       | {}      |
| 2  | 0D2753BE-583B-42CE-B0DA-1FD0171D95C0 | animation | 2       | {}      |
| 3  | 1C2A1131-0261-4D58-81AA-EFAB5285B282 | formation | 1       | {}      |
| 4  | 1E17403F-C590-4CE4-9E79-E1B7C98F97F1 | session   | 1       | {}      |
| 4  | 1E17403F-C590-4CE4-9E79-E1B7C98F97F1 | session   | 2       | {}      |
+----+--------------------------------------+-----------+---------+---------+
```

As you can see we can have multiple versions of the same document (referenced by document_guid). What I need is a count of all documents in the table excluding obsolete version. i.e. If the document 1E17403F-C590-4CE4-9E79-E1B7C98F97F1 has two versions like it shows in the example above then it should only account for one document in the overall count.

I really hope this makes more sense then my last question.

The main problem I have is I need a similar query that returns all the latest versions rather than just the count too.

Comment: How do we know if the version is obsolete already?

Comment: Is "the latest version" any different than "only one of each" here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A useful query would probably look like:

```
-- select the maximum version (and other information, per group)
-- can also add a 'count(1) as version_count' if required
select max(version) as latest_version, title, document_guid
from documents
-- from each group, as divided up by the same guid *see note 1
group by document_guid, title
```

This query returns the *latest* version number; there is always "one latest version" per document.

---

<sup>1</sup> The title, which may be a break in normalization, needs to be part of the group for it to be included in the result columns; if not needed, it can be removed.

If the title is a required field that can *change* across versions then this needs to be written differently - first find the "latest version" and then join it back with the appropriate rows. An example:

```
select t.latest_version, d.title, d.document_guid
from documents d
join (
  select max(version) as latest_version, document_guid
  from documents
  group by document_guid
) t
on t.document_guid = d.document_guid and t.latest_version = d.version
```

And of course this assumes a key of `(document_guid, version)`.

Answer (score 2):

To count distinct document_guids:

```
select count(distinct document_guid) from documents
```

To return the latest version of each document, you can either do a `GROUP BY` (as user2864740's answer), or a `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select * from documents d1
where not exists (select 1 from documents d2
                  where d2.document_guid = d1.document_guid
                    and d2.version > d1.version)
```

I.e. return a row if there are no other with same document_guid that has a higher version number.

Comment: This does return the correct amount although i need a similar query that returns all the latest version rather than a count too.